# Display HTML code in Javascript string

Tags: javascript, html

I hope the title explains what I'd like to achieve. If not, please read on!

I am currently coding a Lorem Ipsum generator (as a learning experience, though I may have it on my site for S&G's)

So far, I've managed to get the code to output a random sentence from a list, into the text box. I've also created a generator for creating Lorem Ipsum bullet lists.
Whenever someone generates some text via the tool, I'd like to have one box with the formatted text (paragraphes, bulleted, etc) and then another box with the raw HTML code, so designers can just copy and paste the code straight into their coding program. So far, I've sorted out the formatted text box, but I'm having issues with the raw HTML.

This is what I've got so far:

[Obviously there's a var listArray at the beginning, but I won't bother adding that.]

```
var randomList = listArray[(Math.floor(Math.random() *listArray.length))]

document.getElementById("textarea").innerHTML = "<li>" + (randomList) + "</li>" + "<li>" + (randomList) + "</li>" + "<li>" + (randomList) + "</li>";
document.getElementById("textarea-code").innerHTML = "<li>" + randomList + "</li>" + "<li>" + randomList + "</li>" + "<li>" + randomList + "</li>";}
```

The second innerHTML line is just a copy of the first, and is the line I want to work on.

How do I get that second line to output:

```
<li> Line 1 </li>
<li>li Line 2 </li>
```

into the HTML text box, instead of putting the list items into a bulleted point?

Comment: Learn how to write `<li>` or any other HTML tags by looking at the source of my edit.

Comment: Yeah, I just worked out a very similar way - can't believe I didn't think of that before! Thanks though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked it out! :D

For those of you who are interested, I used ASCII codes for each of the characters required to make up the  <, /, and >.

For example: <li> is

```
&#60;li&#62;
```

Hope that helps someone else!

Comment: I did almost exactly what you did, but I had to put hyphens inbetween each element of the ASCII codes, because otherwise StackOverflow would actually convert them into the corresponding character. The Code tag didn't help much, either

Comment: I take that back - I retried it, and realised I made a typo first time.

Answer (score 5):

For the second line, use `innerText` not `innerHTML`

```
document.getElementById("textarea-code").innerText = 'your html code'
```

Comment: That would actually make it a bit easier to edit in the future - can HTML (like br/) be used in an innerText section? Because without actual list formatting, it all becomes one big paragraph, and so I would need to manually break it up anyway

Comment: `innerText`, isn't it IE thing only?

Comment: @gdoron: Not according to WebKit Inspector and Firebug. Take a look. :) @tristanojbacon: `innerText` will automatically HTML-encode the value as needed, so `<br />` would HTML-encoded (i.e., be converted to `&lt;br /&gt;`) when you set the `innerText`. I'm not sure if you can arbitrarily insert newlines, but I suspect not given the way browsers munge whitespace.